# How to get shipment amount in VirtueMart

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

I need to receive the goods sum including the delivery cost.

How can I do that?

I receive the order of

```
$order_info = $order_model->getOrder($order_id);
foreach ($order_info['items'] as $item) {   ...$item['amount']; // it's amount }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you get your question more concret? like why you want to get shipment amount? and what exactly shipment amount you want? amount with tax and amount has convert by different currency rate?

If you need to find some object shipment amount from virtuemart, you could find in this file: plugins/vmshipment/weight_countries/weight_countries.php ( if you use weight_countries plugin to calcule the shipment)

```
/**
     * @param VirtueMartCart $cart
     * @param                $method
     * @param                $cart_prices
     * @return int
     */
    function getCosts (VirtueMartCart $cart, $method, $cart_prices) {

        if ($method->free_shipment && $cart_prices['salesPrice'] >= $method->free_shipment) {
            return 0.0;
        } else {
            return $method->shipment_cost + $method->package_fee;
        }
    }
```

But be careful to change the shipment_cost object it has related lots different class inherit, if you want to change the amount calculation I would suggestion use this plugin instead: https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/advanced-shipping-by-rules-for-virtuemart/

Comment: If you need shipment cost in your database sql, you could find in this table: h8q2p_virtuemart_shipment_plg_weight_countries, with column: shipment_cost, if you want to change the amount of calculation then you need to another plugin to recalculated cause it is affect too much object class

Comment: This isn't a forum.  Question details should all be located in one place (the question body).  tess - Please avoid asking for clarifications in your answer.  If you are not sure about what is being asked, please request for details via comments under the question.  tCode- please add all of your details/clarifcations to your question and delete your comments.  These page "repairs" will help future researchers to quickly understand the issue AND volunteers will better understand the resolution that is sought.  Please help SO to be a great resource for everyone.